# Do we want hats? A *puzzling* situation

Tags: discussion, status-completed

*apologizes for terrible pun in title*

I recently received an email from a Community Manager from Stack Exchange:

> Winter Bash 2014 will again be available to **all sites that choose to participate**. We’re redesigning all the hats and adding some extra features to keep things fresh and exciting.

So, my question to you is: **Hats or no hats?**

On the one hand, we currently have a host of other problems (terrible post quality in general comes to mind). Jumping into the hat fever at an already chaotic time might not be the best long-term plan for our site.

But on the other hand, hats are fun!

So, what do you think? Upvote whichever position you agree with, and by December 1st, assuming it's not a close tie, our decision will be sent in to the SE team.

Oh, and if you're *puzzle*d (ha, ha) as to what this whole "hat" thing is about, [here's the FAQ for last year's Winter Bash.](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/faq)

Regardless of what we end up choosing, happy winter!

Comment: Note: **in standard Stack Exchange meta-polling tradition, only upvotes will be counted**. Feel free to downvote symbolically if you really feel like it, though.

Comment: I am confused, per SE policy polling like this shouldn't happen in the first place right, for example a quick google search for "meta poll questions" gives as the first result http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233908/are-poll-style-questions-ever-acceptable-on-meta-sites

Comment: @David For light-hearted fun, it's usually okay.

Comment: @Emrakul Excuse my ignorance... what's this about hats? Is it some kind of satirical joke?

Comment: @d'alar'cop Sorry, I completely forgot to explain this whole Winter Bash event in my meta post. Must have been that pesky tin foil hat blocking my brain waves. Anyway, I've edited my post with a link to last year's FAQ.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain more clearly the direct relationship between having hats and the current controversies on meta?

Comment: Do we get to know the colors of our own hats? /joke

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Yes!

Hats are fun! Besides, anyone who doesn't want to join in can turn them off.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ptSYdRX.png

Comment: Do you think an individually opt-in (like FAQ said Stack Overflow had last year) would be a significantly difference, or it is eventually the same as giving hats to everyone in the first place? (I am supposing this choice will be available this year too, obviously)

Comment: The current vote is 21-18, which is pretty close to a tie. However, after consultation with a Stack Exchange Community Manager (and some other ♦s), looks like we're going to go with **Yes** this year!

Comment: http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/seuss/images/5/5a/Hooray!_Hooray!.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width/800?cb=20130516170723

Answer (score 8):

## No!

There's too much other stuff going on right now. Maybe next year!

*Author note: This has my upvote.*

Comment: Since you're voting "no". I'm wondering, how come?

Comment: @d'alar'cop I explained that in the meta question: "O n the one hand, we currently have a host of other problems (terrible post quality in general comes to mind). Jumping into the hat fever at an already chaotic time might not be the best long-term plan for our site."

Comment: Unfortunately, I would have to vote no. I agree with you - the site quality has been declining. I feel like hats would encourage users to post bad questions, answer poorly, or even cheat the system somehow just to get hats.